# React native component absolute overflow

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a component with absolute position, zIndex > 0 to make it render above other components. I am setting position: absolute. The problem is that if the component is close to the bottom of the screen, it gets cropped. I don't want to make it push the components below it. I want it to be above. The snack is here:
[enter link description here](https://snack.expo.io/@sorinbogdan/403ae2)

I also tried with ScrollView but the result was even worse, nothing was being displayed anymore if I set overflow:'visible' to the scrollview. Any ideas how I could get this working ?

Comment: I can not understand your problem clearly, could you give an image example?

Answer (score 0):

please remove all overflow: 'visible' style.